# Keyboard opacity

Tags: windows-phone-7

It is possible to change the keyboard opacity on Windows Phone 7.5? I saw an [article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx) that explains how to create a custom keyboard but it was not quite what I wanted to do. I want to use the WP7 keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the layout of the software keyboard on Windows Phone.

Comment: And what about this app? How did they add opacity to software keyboard? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/b450671d-0a06-4df7-96ec-dd2e81f9184b

Comment: It's a custom keyboard, not the build-in SIP.